# Increment and Decrement price value on Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

i'm trying to do an price counter synchronizing with increment and decrement buttons, but the price is not changing when i click one of the buttons (+/-) this is not working, how can i solve this issue? Thanks!!!

```js
$('#plus').click(function add() {
    var $qtde = $("#quantity");
    var a = $qtde.val();
    
    a++;
    $("#minus").attr("disabled", !a);
    $qtde.val(a);
});
$("#minus").attr("disabled", !$("#quantity").val());

$('#minus').click(function minust() {
    var $qtde = $("#quantity");
    var b = $qtde.val();
    if (b >= 1) {
        b--;
        $qtde.val(b);
    }
    else {
        $("#minus").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});

/* On change */
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function updatePrice()
    {
        var price = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
        var total = (price + 1) * 1.05;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total-price").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup, focus", "#quantity", updatePrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" id="minus" />
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="" name="quantity" />
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" />
<br />
<input id="total-price" readonly="readonly" value=""/>
```

Comment: Logical changes to an input do not trigger a change event.  thus clicking the plus or minus does not trigger a change event when changing the quantity.  Just call updatePrice after you logically change the quantity value.  Though that will be an issue with how you have updatePrice scoped inside the document ready, unlike the other bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your binding to update whenever there is a click on an input, you'll get the behavior that you are expecting.

```js
$('#plus').click(function add() {
  var $qtde = $("#quantity");
  var a = $qtde.val();

  a++;
  $("#minus").attr("disabled", !a);
  $qtde.val(a);
});
$("#minus").attr("disabled", !$("#quantity").val());

$('#minus').click(function minust() {
  var $qtde = $("#quantity");
  var b = $qtde.val();
  if (b >= 1) {
    b--;
    $qtde.val(b);
  } else {
    $("#minus").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});

/* On change */
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updatePrice() {
    var price = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
    var total = (price + 1) * 1.05;
    var total = total.toFixed(2);
    $("#total-price").val(total);
  }
  // On the click of an input, update the price
  $(document).on("click", "input", updatePrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" id="minus" />
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="" name="quantity" />
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" />
<br />
<input id="total-price" readonly="readonly" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="sp-quantity">
    <div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; ">
         
      <div class="sp-input">
        <input type="text" class="quantity-input" value="1">

        <div class="button" style="cursor: pointer;">
            +
        </div>
        <div class="button" style="cursor: pointer;">
            -
        </div>
      </div>

     
      
      <p>custom filed</p>
      <div class="sp-input">
        <input type="text" class="quantity-input-db" value="1.8" step="1.8">

        <div class="button" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
            +
        </div>
        <div class="button" style="cursor: pointer;">
            -
        </div>

      </div>

     
    </div>
</div>  




<script type="text/javascript">
        // debugger;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on("click", function() {
     
      var $db_value = $('.db_value').val();

      var $quantity = $('.quantity_input').val();

      var db_valu_fix = 1.8;

      var $button = $(this),
      $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quantity-input");
      
      var oldValue_q = $input.val();

      var $db_value = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quantity-input-db");

      var oldValue_db = $db_value.val();

        console.log(oldValue_db);
      

        if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {

            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue_q) + 1;

            newdbVal = parseFloat(oldValue_db) + 1;

            //newdbVal.toFixed(2);


        } 
        else {
        
            if (oldValue_q > 0) {

              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue_q) - 1;

              newdbVal = parseFloat(oldValue_db) - 1;

              newdbVal = Math.round(newdbVal * 100) / 100;
            
            } else {

              newVal = 1;
            
            }

        }

        $input.val(newVal);
        $db_value.val(newdbVal);
    });


    // $(".ddd").on("click", function(step) {
    //  var a=$(".quantity-input").val();
    //  var attr=$(".quantity-input").attr(step);

    //  var getValue=a/1;
    //      console.log(attr);
    // });

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```